# How to activate a script on an object from a script in another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a racing game and am having a problem with making the controls disabled until the countdown says go. The end of the countdown script is:

```
CountDownNumber.SetActive(false);
CountDownNumber.GetComponent<Text>().text = "GO!";
countdownAudio.Play(); //Change to Go Audio
CountDownNumber.SetActive(true);
```

And when this part is run I want the script in the car object to be enabled. The way I had tried was by using the line:

```
usercontrol.GetComponent(CarController).enabled = true;
```

or

```
usercontrol.GetComponent<CarController>().enabled = true;
```

Neither of which are successful as the error message is:

> Assets/CountDown.cs(41,34): error CS0103: The name `CarController' does not exist in the current context

But this is the name of the script in the GameObject that I want to enable.

Any ideas about how I fix this?

If it helps, the car is from the Standard Assets and so it is that Car Controller script that I want to enable on go.

Comment: You may need to add a `using` statement so the C# compiler knows which CarController you're referring to.

Comment: Can you try accessing all components with this `Component[] comp = usercontrol.GetComponents(typeof(Component))` and check by printing array elements if `CarController` is one of them?

Comment: make sure both the script and class are called `CarController` with the exact same spelling

Comment: @AliKanat the problme is not whether the component is on the object or not but that the type `CarController` is not recognized at compile time

Comment: if you get this problem only in VisualStudio it worked for me to close and reopen VS or in some very bad cases close VS and Unity, remove all files and folders except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` and restart Unity and let it rebuild and compile everything

Comment: Thanks guys, the script and class are both are called CarController. Also I added the line 'using UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car;' and now my error message is *Assets/CountDown.cs(42,34): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected*

Comment: I've got it working now guys! Thank you I just added the using standard assets and the second line to enabled the script:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where missing a `using` statement

```
using UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car;
```

---

than make sure to use the second one

```
usercontrol.GetComponent<CarController>().enabled = true;
```

---

the first one would either require a string instead like

```
usercontrol.GetComponent("CarController").enabled = true;
```

or the usage of `typeof` like

```
usercontrol.GetComponent(typeof(CarController)).enabled = true;
```

check the [GetComponent API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)